# Spring Controller implementing ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

I am implementing WebSocket in spring 4.0.5. The client(browser) keep a connection to the server. When my service layer update some record at the back end, I want to inform the client which subscribe to the particular topic.

I want my Controller to listen to my ApplicationEvent and publish it to the WebSocket client. Is this possible?

I have another listener implemented in my service layer and it can capture the event. 
Is it true that the controller cannot listen to the ApplicationEvent?

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.geneoz.service.event.MessageEvent;

@Controller
public class ApplicationEventObservorController implements ApplicationListener<MessageEvent> {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationEventObservorController.class);

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationEventObservorController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        logger.debug("Initialising ApplicationEventObservorController");
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(MessageEvent event) {
        logger.debug("Captured event. " + event);
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/update", event.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't understand what the controller (normally a singleton) will do if multiple browsers are simultaneously connected. Do you keep a track of active sessions in a controller ?